# Vue async call REST API in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

My async actions do not run correctly. Im new to Vue and JS and I am not sure what is happening here. I placed some `confirm()` dialogs within my code, to see which line passed and which not.

Within the `ScanView.vue` I call my `addProduct` action. I get the confirm dialog saying "addProduct" and dispatch calles the next `callAPI` action where I get the `"callAPI"` confirm dialog but nothing more. Seems like `fetch()` isnt working at all, because no any other dialog is shown. What am I doing wrong?

ScanView.vue

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  methods: {
    scanEan() {
      // QR Code Scanner Logic
      this.$store.dispatch("addProduct", ean);
    }
});
```

main.js

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    products: [{
      name: 'Produkt',
      ean: '123',
      amount: '1',
      smallImageUrl: 'smImage',
      mediumImageUrl: 'mdImage',
      largeImageUrl: 'lgImage',
      expiration: []
    }]
  },
  mutations: {
    addProduct(state, product) {
      state.products.unshift(product);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addProduct(context, ean) {
      confirm("addProduct: " + ean);
      context.dispatch('callAPI', ean);
    },
    callAPI(context, ean) {
      confirm("callAPI: ");
      fetch("https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/" + ean + ".json") //
        .then(response => {
          confirm("reesponse");
          return response.json();
        }
        ) //
        .then(data => {
          confirm("data: " + data);
          context.dispatch('saveProduct', data);
        });
    },
    saveProduct(context, data) {
      confirm("saveProduct: ");
      const name = data.product.product_name;
      const ean = data.code;
      const smImage = data.product.image_front_thumb_url;
      const mdImage = data.product.image_front_small_url;
      const lgImage = data.product.image_front_url;
      const expiration = new Array();
      const date = new Date(data.product.expiration_date);
      expiration.push(date);
      const product = new Product(
        name,
        ean,
        smImage,
        mdImage,
        lgImage,
        expiration
      )
      confirm("Produktdata: " + product);
      context.commit('addProduct', product);
    }
  }
});

app.use(store);
```

**EDIT**
I build a simulate button for better testing. QR Scanning does not work in Browser.

**Result** It does work in Browser. But not on my emulator or android device. Seems like fetch() isnt the right way with ionic-vue. If I catch the error I got TypeError: Failed to fetch...

```
<template>
    <button @click="simulateScan">Simulate Scan</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    simulateScan() {
      this.$store.dispatch('addProduct', 737628064502);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: How do you pass your `ean` variable to your `scanEan` method? right now it looks like it will be `undefined` inside your `callAPI` action

Comment: You should add `.catch(error => {console.log(error)})` to `fetch` and check what error occurred.

Comment: @StevenSiebert Thanks man! Sadly I cant console.log(..) because I work with an android emulator and dunno how to get device logs but I printed it with an dialog.

Comment: Please add in title this is for mobile, not for desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Final Solution**

fetch() does not work on android. You have to use something like cordova-http, capacitor-http, ionic-http or else. I used capacitorcommunity-http.

```
npm install @capacitor-community/http
npx cap sync
```

```
import { Http } from '@capacitor-community/http';    

[...]

callAPI(context, ean) {
      var eanurl = "https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/" + ean + ".json";
      Http.get({ url: eanurl}) //
        .then(response => {
          return response.data;
        }
        ) //
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          context.dispatch('saveProduct', data);
        }).catch(error => confirm(error));
    },

[...]
```